# Selenium/Selenide: test code refactor for presence of shadowroot

Tags: java, class, selenium, automated-tests

I'm working on an automated tests project, where I create UI tests with Selenium/Selenide in java for a web-based media player, that is then integrated in other products of my company. However, there was a UI for that Player (as a React component) in the application my team is developping before there was a UI for the Player itself, in standalone. So, basically, I have to redesign the code that I had for both the application and the standalone Player: the goal is to create the code in the Player package, to then import it to the application test project.

The problem here is that, in the standalone version, the Player HTML code contains a shadowroot, and the Player React component in the main application does not. This means that I have to use WebElements in the standalone version, whereas I am to continue using SelenideElements in the main application test code (to be able to deal with some particular interactions that occur in the main application and that are not possible in the standalone Player).

Normally, for each "part" of the Web page, I create a "Client" class that contains the methods to find the elements, and then to perform the interactions with them and/or verify their state. Since the two UIs have the differences I explained above, I imagine that I will have to have two different sets of Client classes. I was thinking of doing something like creating another class or an interface to try to find the shadowroot element, and, depending on whether it was found on the HTML code or not, initialising one of the two sets of clients.

So, my question is, how can I overall structure all of this in terms of classes/interfaces/methods, so I can have as little doubled code as possible in both Client sets?

Any help is welcome, even if it's just to show me that I'm thinking about this in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I hit such a case

> Since the two UIs have the differences ... I will have to have two different sets of Client classes ... creating another class or an interface to try to find the shadowroot element, and, depending on whether it was found on the HTML code or not, initialising one of the two sets of clients.

and especially for `as little doubled code as possible in both Client sets`, in my experience [Strategy](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm) provides quite suitable solution. It defines a family of algorithms, encapsulate each one, and make them interchangeable. Also lets the algorithm vary independently from clients that use it. So, you may think for the algorithms to be your test steps and the clients are the apps loaded.